# Apache geode cachelistener not executing

Tags: gemfire, geode

This is a newbie question, thanks for reading it. So I start a Geode server cache process with a replicated region like this:

```
gfsh>start locator --name=myLocator
```

and a server process

```
start server --cache-xml-file=D:\Geode\config\cache.xml --name=myGeode --locators=localhost[10334]
```

The cache.xml defined a replicated region called `myRegion`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache/cache-1.0.xsd" 
    version="1.0">
<cache-server/>
<region name="myRegion" refid="REPLICATE"/>
</cache>
```

and then I am using the Pivotal Native Client for .Net with which in another process I start up a client cache with a cache event listener as follows:

```
CacheFactory cacheFactory = CacheFactory.CreateCacheFactory();
Cache cache = cacheFactory.SetSubscriptionEnabled(true).Create();
RegionFactory regionFactory = cache.CreateRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY);
IRegion<string, string> region = regionFactory.Create<string, string>("myRegion");
region.AttributesMutator.SetCacheListener(new MyEventHandler<string, string>());
```

The MyEventHandler is:

```
public class MyEventHandler<TKey, TVal> : ICacheListener<TKey, TVal>
{
    public void AfterCreate(EntryEvent<TKey, TVal> ev)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received AfterCreate event for: {0}", ev.Key.ToString());
    }
...
}
```

and then again in a third process I create another cache for that process to put some data into `myRegion`. It's the same setup as the second process without the listener:

```
CacheFactory cacheFactory = CacheFactory.CreateCacheFactory();
Cache cache = cacheFactory.SetSubscriptionEnabled(true).Create();
RegionFactory regionFactory = cache.CreateRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY);
IRegion<string, string> region = regionFactory.Create<string, string>("myRegion");
region["testKey"] = "testValue";
```

The problem is after the third process puts the test data into `myRegion` (that I can see on the server so that's working) the listener in the second process doesn't see it. What am I missing?

Thanks...

Comment: Per @swapnil below registering interest before setting the cache listener is what did it: `region.GetSubscriptionService().RegisterAllKeys();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client where you have the listener, you need to [register interest in either all or a subset of key](http://gemfire-native.docs.pivotal.io/geode/client-cache/registering-interest-for-entries.html) so that the server knows to send updates to the client.

Comment: https://geode.apache.org/docs/geode-native/19/regions/registering-interest-for-entries.html